# Upload file with multer in a ftp server in nestjs application

Tags: ftp, nestjs, multer, ftp-server

I am developing a nestjs application and i need to upload multimedia file in ftp server and stream it.

i can save and stream files in my local server but i want to store files in my ftp server.

i have already done this parts for upload:

```
@Controller('')
export class FileController{
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('track', {
        dest: './uploads/files',
        storage: diskStorage({
            destination: './uploads/files',
            filename: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, uuidv4() + '.mp3')
            }
        })
    }))
    async createTrack(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
        return catchAsync(async () => {
            return new AppException(file).getResponse()
        })
    }

}
```

and for stream:

```
@Controller('')
export class FileController{
    @Get('file/:file_id')
    @Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    async getStreamTracks(@Param('file_id') file_id: string) {
        return catchAsync(async () => {

            return await this.filesService.getStream(file_id)
        })
    }

}
```

now i want to modify this two parts to make me able to upload to ftp server and stream from ftp server.